# How to deal with "data of class uneval" error from ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

While trying to overlay a new line to a existing `ggplot`, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval
```

The first part of my code works fine. Below is an image of "recent" hourly wind generation data from a Midwestern United States electric power market.

[image: Recent Hourly Wind Data]

Now I want to overlay the last two days worth of observations in Red.  It should be easy but I cant figure out why I am getting a error.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Below is a reproducible example:

```
# Read in Wind data
fname <- "https://www.midwestiso.org/Library/Repository/Market%20Reports/20130510_hwd_HIST.csv"
df <- read.csv(fname, header=TRUE, sep="," , skip=7)
df <- df[1:(length(df$MKTHOUR)-5),]

# format variables
df$MWh <- as.numeric(df$MWh)
df$Datetime <- strptime(df$MKTHOUR, "%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p")

# Create some variables
df$Date  <- as.Date(df$Datetime)
df$HrEnd <- df$Datetime$hour+1

# Subset recent and last data
last.obs  <- range(df$Date)[2]
df.recent <- subset(df, Date %in% seq(last.obs-30, last.obs-2, by=1))
df.last   <- subset(df, Date %in% seq(last.obs-2,  last.obs,   by=1))

# plot recent in Grey
p <- ggplot(df.recent, aes(HrEnd, MWh, group=factor(Date))) + 
  geom_line(color="grey") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,24,1)) +
  labs(y="MWh") + 
  labs(x="Hour Ending") + 
  labs(title="Hourly Wind Generation")    
p

# plot last two days in Red
p <- p + geom_line(df.last, aes(HrEnd, MWh, group=factor(Date)), color="red")  
p
```

Answer (score 165, accepted):

when you add a new data set to a geom you need to use the `data=` argument. Or put the arguments in the proper order `mapping=..., data=...`.  Take a look at the arguments for `?geom_line`.

Thus:

```
p + geom_line(data=df.last, aes(HrEnd, MWh, group=factor(Date)), color="red")
```

Or:

```
p + geom_line(aes(HrEnd, MWh, group=factor(Date)), df.last, color="red")
```

Comment: ouch thats kind of embarrasing!! but I wont ever make that mistake again.  Thanks Justin

Comment: No its not! and yes you will!  Glad I could steer you in the right direction and now its here for posterity.

Answer (score 13):

Another cause is accidentally putting the `data=...` inside the `aes(...)` instead of outside:

```
RIGHT:
ggplot(data=df[df$var7=='9-06',], aes(x=lifetime,y=rep_rate,group=mdcp,color=mdcp) ...)

WRONG:
ggplot(aes(data=df[df$var7=='9-06',],x=lifetime,y=rep_rate,group=mdcp,color=mdcp) ...)
```

In particular this can happen when you prototype your plot command with `qplot()`, which doesn't use an explicit `aes()`, then edit/copy-and-paste it into a `ggplot()`

```
qplot(data=..., x=...,y=..., ...)

ggplot(data=..., aes(x=...,y=...,...))
```

It's a pity ggplot's error message isn't *Missing 'data' argument!* instead of this cryptic nonsense, because that's what this message often means.

Answer (score 4):

This could also occur if you refer to a variable in the data.frame that doesn't exist. For example, recently I forgot to tell ddply to summarize by one of my variables that I used in geom_line to specify line color. Then, ggplot didn't know where to find the variable I hadn't created in the summary table, and I got this error.

Comment: This error could also happen if you forget to pipe ggplot with +. I accidentally used dplyr's %>% operator and ggplot didn't get the lines it needed to complete the plot.