# How to use a solid square as the legend key in ggplot2 geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, boxplot

I am trying to use R **ggplot2** package to make a boxplot.

However I can only get legend like this. Is there anyway I can change those legend key to just a solid square, instead of using those small box with central line?

The code I used is:

```
print(ggplot(mydata,aes(x=factor(sp),fill=factor(CommunityType),y=Abundance*100))+geom_boxplot(show_guide=FALSE)
      +theme(axis.text = element_text(colour = "black",size=10))
      +scale_y_continuous(" RA (%) ")+scale_x_discrete(limits=taxalist[1:5]," ")
      +scale_fill_manual(name = "MY type", values = mycol[1:nmc])
      +theme_bw() + guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL))+theme(legend.position=c(1,1),legend.justification=c(1,1)) 
      +theme(legend.key = element_blank(),legend.key.size = unit(1.5, "lines"))
      +theme( panel.grid.major = element_blank(),  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),  panel.background = element_blank())  )
```

Sorry I cannot image here to describe my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the legend shown as simple squares, using a variant of a hack that I have seen Winston Change use [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/#hiding-slashes-in-the-legend). (I am using the diamonds dataset.)

[image]

The idea is to plot geom_points (whose legend you can control, and to suppress the boxplot's legend altogether)

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=diamonds, aes(x=cut, y=mean(depth), color=clarity), shape=15, size=5)
p <- p + guides(color=guide_legend(title=NULL)) 
p <- p + theme(legend.key = element_blank())
p <- p  + geom_boxplot(data=diamonds,aes(x=cut,fill=factor(clarity),y=depth)) + guides(fill=FALSE)
p
```

Also check out Hadley's [Legend-Attributes page on github](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Legend-Attributes)

Comment: Thanks @Ram Narasimhan! I tried your code, but always report       Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval. You know how to solve that problem?

Comment: If you are getting that error message, make sure that you are explicitly stating the `data =` argument. See this question, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486819/how-to-deal-with-data-of-class-uneval-in-ggplot The code above works for me.

Comment: Hey @Ram Narasimhan. There is one problem you may noticed that in the the plot you uploaded, the first column there is a small square there which is unexpected. I suppose in all five cuts there are also a same square but in different color there. I had the same problem now. How can we get rid of that? Thanks!

Comment: Yes I see that. Ways to get around that is to move the y axis value (instead of `y=mean(depth)` ) or to make the size smaller, so that the square gets smaller.